# No schema in Google cloud sql

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, schema

I uploaded the dataset just fine but when I went to begin, it said there was no schema. I went and the schema tab was empty. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Cloud SQL or BigQuery? Those are NOT the same

Comment: Do you have a database in Cloud SQL?